# Encoding problem in Vaadin 8 Framework application when building with Gradle in Windows

Tags: java, windows, gradle, character-encoding, vaadin8

When you use the Gradle plugin [com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin) for building [Vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/vaadin-8) applications everything works fine as long as you use Linux or Mac. `setContent(new Label("A B C Å Ä Ö"))` prints out the characters `A B C Å Ä Ö` as expected.

However, if you run the application in Windows the following characters are printed out: `A B C Ã… Ã„ Ã–`.

How can I fix the problem?

See below the essential files in a [sample project](https://github.com/haba713/devsoap-vaadin-windows-encoding).

build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin' version '2.0.0.beta2'
}
```

ExampleUI.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExampleUI extends UI { 
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        setContent(new Label("A B C Å Ä Ö"));
    }
}
```

ExampleServlet.java

```java
@WebServlet(
    asyncSupported=false,
    urlPatterns={"/*","/VAADIN/*"},
    initParams={
        @WebInitParam(name="ui", value="haba713.ExampleUI")
    })
public class ExampleServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

Environment

- Windows 10 Pro, version   20H2, OS build  19042.985
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.282-b08, mixed mode)
- Gradle 5.6.4
- com.devsoap.plugin.vaadin version 2.0.0.beta2

Comment: If it's a _console_ application then use [`chcp 65001`](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html) _before_ running it…

Comment: No, it isn't. Vaadin 8 is a GWT based web framework.

Comment: Don’t send us elsewhere to figure out your problem statement. That is your job as the author of this Question. Post relevant details and context here.

Comment: I included the essential file contents in the question.

Comment: It's a simple [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) case of the following kind (example in Python): `'Å Ä Ö'.encode('utf-8').decode('cp1252')` returns `'Ã… Ã„ Ã–'`.

Comment: I don't want to fix it in a code because everything works fine in Linux and Mac. I've tried `vaadinCompile { jvmArgs = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"] }` and `vaadinRun { jvmArgs = ["-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"] }` in `build.gradle` without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java sources on Linux and Mac are UTF-8 by the default encoding (editor), and evidently also compiled by UTF-8 (compiler).

On Windows with unchanged sources in the editor `Å Ä Ö` would be seen as weird character pairs. If the *editor* is explicitly set to UTF-8 they are shown correctly.

But evidently the *compiler* uses the default platform encoding, yielding those pairs.

So set the gradle compiler encoding.

```
compileJava {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

*(Not much experience with gradle.)*

As the IDE often shadows the build process of gradle, also set the editor/compiler encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Thank you Joop Eggen! This one resolved the issue.